# Logging into google spreadsheets with RGoogleDocs

Tags: r, ssl, authentication, google-sheets

According to the directions on https://github.com/hammer/google-spreadsheets-to-r-dataframe :
I try to login via:

> sheets.con = getGoogleDocsConnection(getGoogleAuth(, , service = "wise"))
>   spreadsheets = getDocs(sheets.con)

After the second line I get the error:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

What the issue, how do I get it to accept the certificates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either pass on `verifypeer=FALSE` to RCurl::getURL:

```
sheets.con = getGoogleDocsConnection(getGoogleAuth(<name>,<psw>, service = "wise")) 
spreadsheets = getDocs(sheets.con, ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)
```

Or pass on `cainfo=system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")` instead.